Where does it say that If a Person has Zera Levatalah the shadim take a day to be created untill the night
I heard if a person has zera levatalah the shadim or deamon that he created take a day to be created untill the night time where they fully form where does it say this?

Welcome to MiYodeya John and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Welcome. Where did you hear this?
